# Perspective transformation of image using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, perspective

I'm trying to draw a perspective projection of an image on a canvas
I've used [perspective-transform](https://github.com/jlouthan/perspective-transform) to calculate the transformation matrix. Later on, I've used that matrix to populate CSS transform.matrix3d

```
const transform = PerspT([0, 0, width, 0, 0, height, width, height], [dest1.x, dest1.y, dest2.x, dest2.y, dest3.x, dest3.y, dest4.x, dest4.y]);
let t = transform.coeffs;
t = [
  t[0], t[3], 0, t[6],
  t[1], t[4], 0, t[7],
  0, 0, 1, 0,
  t[2], t[5], 0, t[8]
];
t = 'matrix3d(' + t.join(', ') + ')';
renderer.setStyle(element, 'transform', t);
```

It worked great but I also wanted to save the image and therefore I've used [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). Unfortunately, html2canvas doesn't support CSS transform.

Now I try to implement the CSS transform all by myself on HTML canvas. I know that a perspective transformation doesn't work with 2D context but I can render WebGL scene on a canvas. I could just set the image as a texture of the 3D plane, apply the transformation matrix and render it. However, to render the 3D scene I need to set up the position of a camera. I don't have that kind of position in the context of my application. How does CSS 3D transform work without the additional info about a camera? How could I implement it using WebGL/Three.js?

I've found some solutions with texture mapping in pure JS but this kind of rendering is a stress for a web browser. From my experience with OpenGL, I think that I'm looking for some kind of UV texture mapping algorithm.

I just want to perform this kind of transformation based on 4 source and 4 destination points:
[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_sandbox.html.

Comment: That example uses a camera too.